# Can not add odata service reference

Tags: .net, sql-server, odata, olingo

I'm using Apache olingo to produce OData entities from a MSSQL database.
My service works good from browser (I can get all entities using uri conventions from odata), but when I want to add service reference from other .net project I get this error:

> Failure of the special tool "DataServicesCoreClientGenerator '. !RmYV3! Data service client code-generation failed: The element can not contain text. The content model is empty .. #Рlос Р!

What is wrong and where should I look for the problem?

Comment: OData v2 or OData v4? If you're using OData v4 (Olingo has versions for both v2 and v4) you will need a v4-compatible client. The .NET client moved to a T4 template for OData v4: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9b786c0e-79d1-4a50-89a5-125e57475937.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, OData v2

Comment: I created new service from scratch, but using odata4j. The problem still exists.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a OData key value to my Entity Framework class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161929/how-do-i-add-a-odata-key-value-to-my-entity-framework-class)

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate. My question is about java service.